# Testing Apps on a Device

Tags: trigger.io

When using **trigger.io** **toolkit**, there's an option that says

```
"Build and immediately run your app, either locally, on a simulator or on a connected device."
```

How do you run the app on a Connected Device? I want to see the app on my iPhone and see how it behaves directly. Is this possible?

Thanks
Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're working on windows with an iPhone that's iOS8 because that's where you currently can't run your app directly on a connected device.

What we did to "fix" this is creating a Development Provisioning Profile with the UDID's of our test devices and added this to config -> tools in the trigger.io toolkit. In the forge you now select package -> iOS giving you a .ipa file. This .ipa can now be installed using iTunes on your test devices.

It's a bit longer than just clicking run on device like you can for Android but at least you don't have to send it to testflight and wait for apple's approval.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but it depends on your os.

If your on a Mac you can deploy to both ios and android devices from forge, just connect them via usb and build, grated you need to make sure iTunes sees your devices etc.. there are guides on the trigger site

If you are on Windows, you are unfortunate out of luck right now, this used to work but ios8 broke this so if your building on ios7 you could still do it on Windows, otherwise you would need to use testpiolet from apple